# listView.isItemChecked(position) is always true

Tags: android

I want to create a contact list in which I can select multiple contact. but the problem is that when i am clicking on the item, `isItemChecked` is always true even for a fresh list. i have applied `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` to listView.

**Here is the code.**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (listView.isItemChecked(position)){
                    listView.setItemChecked(position, false);
                    personCounter--;
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    Log.w("item unchecked", "true");
                }else{
                    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    personCounter++;
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.personSelectBackground));
                    Log.w("item got checked", "true");
                }
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add " + personCounter + " person.");
            }
        });
```

There is another problem too. When I am changing the background for view it is reflecting on multiple view (every eight view in list is changing). i know that it is because of recycle view, but how to solve this problem.

I also want to make this list like gmail list where selecting email modifies the image with a tick mark. suggest me any tutorial related to this.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328869/why-does-isitemchecked-return-true-when-in-actionmode it looks like they got the same issue

Comment: i am not sure about the other issues but in your case i would have used my own adapter to handle everything.

Comment: @YamenNassif, he is using onItemLongClick instead of onItemClick to solve this problem but i can't.

Comment: programmatically there shouldn't be an issue between onclick and onlongclick.

Comment: @YamenNassif, OnItemLongClick is working fine but OnItemClick is not. but i don't want to use OnItemLongClick.